# jQuery clone and bind event issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I m trying to clone one div with some elements on **a** tag click event when clone is happening I am changing **a** tag to delete and bind click event. Whenever I add more clone I will remove a delete tag from all previous clone and keep it on last clone. when user click on last **a** tag with click event, I will remove last clone tag and add delete to previous clone which will become last clone.

Every thing works until when "**delete to previous clone which will become last clone**" but my delete a tag will stop working. Kindly let me know what I am doing wrong.

My jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/milindsaraswala/6mt29a6x/ (Sorry for not putting any css in my jsfiddle as it is huge)

Sample code of jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".addFlightBtn").click(function () {
            $(".flightRows").append($(".flightRow:first").clone());
            $(".flightRow").find(".exclude").removeClass("exclude");
            var flightLength = $(".flightRows").children(".flightRow").length;
            $(".flightRow:last").find("#lbFlight").html("Flight " + flightLength); 
            $(".flightRow:last").find(".addFlightBtn").addClass("exclude delFlightBtn").removeClass("addFlightBtn").html("Delete Flight");
            $(".flightRow").not(':first').find('a').not('.exclude').remove();
            $(".flightRow:last").find(".delFlightBtn").bind("click", function () {
                $(this).closest(".flightRow").prev().find(".searchBtnHolder").html('<a href="#" class="exclude delFlightBtn">Delete Flight</a>');
                $(this).closest(".flightRow").remove();
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Your code is fine except use delegate event binding when you adding html
>   dynamically.

I have only changed your delete event handler this is how. Here's **[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6mt29a6x/1/)**

```
$(document).on("click", ".delFlightBtn", function() {
  if ($(".flightRow").length > 2) {
    $(this).closest(".flightRow").prev()
   .find(".searchBtnHolder")
   .html('<a href="#" class="exclude delFlightBtn">Delete Flight</a>');
  }
  $(this).closest(".flightRow").remove();
});
```

After fixing the event handler you will find another problem which is fixed by this line

```
if ($(".flightRow").length > 2) {
   $(this).closest(".flightRow").prev()
   .find(".searchBtnHolder")
   .html('<a href="#" class="exclude delFlightBtn">Delete Flight</a>');
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".addFlightBtn").click(function() {
    $(".flightRows").append($(".flightRow:first").clone());
    $(".flightRow").find(".exclude").removeClass("exclude");
    var flightLength = $(".flightRows").children(".flightRow").length;
    $(".flightRow:last").find("#lbFlight").html("Flight " + flightLength);
    $(".flightRow:last").find(".addFlightBtn").addClass("exclude delFlightBtn").removeClass("addFlightBtn").html("Delete Flight");
    $(".flightRow").not(':first').find('a').not('.exclude').remove();
  });
  $(document).on("click", ".delFlightBtn", function() {
    if ($(".flightRow").length > 2) {
      $(this).closest(".flightRow").prev().find(".searchBtnHolder").html('<a href="#" class="exclude delFlightBtn">Delete Flight</a>');
    }
    $(this).closest(".flightRow").remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="midcontainer pad20">
  <div class="content-area fullWidth whiteBg">
    <div class="pad15">
      <div class="flightRows">
        <div class="row flightRow">
          <p><strong><span id="lbFlight">Flight 1</span></strong></p>
          <div class="depCol1">
            <label for="seldcity1" id="lbDeptCity">Departure city</label>
            <br>
            <select>
              <option>Abu Dhabi (AUH)</option>
              <option>Amman (AMM)</option>
              <option>Bahrain (BAH)</option>
              <option>Bangkok (BKK)</option>
              <option>Beirut (BEY)</option>
              <option>Cairo (CAI)</option>
              <option>Thiruvananthapuram (TRV)</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="depCol1">
            <label for="seldcity2" id="lbArvlCity">Arrival city</label>
            <br>
            <select>
              <option>Abu Dhabi (AUH)</option>
              <option>Amman (AMM)</option>
              <option>Bahrain (BAH)</option>
              <option>Bangkok (BKK)</option>
              <option>Beirut (BEY)</option>
              <option>Cairo (CAI)</option>
              <option>Thiruvananthapuram (TRV)</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="depCol1">
            <label for="selddate1" id="lbDeptDate">Departing</label>
            <br />
            <input name="selddate1" type="text" id="selddate1" autocomplete="off" class="datepicker calIcon hasDatepicker">
          </div>
          <div class="searchBtnHolder"><a href="#" class="addFlightBtn">Add another Flight</a></div>
          <div class="clear"></div>
          <hr />
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--<div class="row">
    <p><strong>Flight 2</strong></p>
    <div class="depCol1">
     <label for="seldcity1" id="lbDeptCity">Departure city</label><br>
     <select>
      <option>Abu Dhabi (AUH)</option>
      <option>Amman (AMM)</option>
      <option>Bahrain (BAH)</option>
      <option>Bangkok (BKK)</option>
      <option>Beirut (BEY)</option>
      <option>Cairo (CAI)</option>
      <option>Thiruvananthapuram (TRV)</option>
     </select>
    </div>
    <div class="depCol1">
     <label for="seldcity2" id="lbArvlCity">Arrival city</label><br>
     <select>
      <option>Abu Dhabi (AUH)</option>
      <option>Amman (AMM)</option>
      <option>Bahrain (BAH)</option>
      <option>Bangkok (BKK)</option>
      <option>Beirut (BEY)</option>
      <option>Cairo (CAI)</option>
      <option>Thiruvananthapuram (TRV)</option>
     </select>
    </div>
    <div class="depCol1">
     <label for="selddate1" id="lbDeptDate">Departing</label><br />
     <input name="selddate1" type="text" id="selddate1" autocomplete="off" class="datepicker calIcon hasDatepicker">
    </div>
    <div class="searchBtnHolder"><a href="#" class="delFlightBtn">Delete Flight</a></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <hr />
   </div>-->
      <div class="row">
        <p><strong>Passengers</strong></p>
        <div class="depCol1">
          <label for="seladults" id="lbAdults">Adults</label>
          <br>
          <select name="seladults" id="seladults" class="wth70 noMargin">
            <option value="1" selected="">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
          </select>
          <br>
          <span class="ageCount" id="lbAge12">(Age 12+)</span>
        </div>
        <div class="depCol1">
          <label for="selchildren" id="lbChildren">Children</label>
          <br>
          <select name="selchildren" id="selchildren" class="wth70">
            <option value="0" selected="">0</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
          </select>
          <br>
          <span class="ageCount" id="lbChild">(Age 2-11)</span>
        </div>
        <div class="depCol1">
          <label for="selinfants" id="lbInfants">Infants</label>
          <br>
          <select name="selinfants" id="selinfants" class="wth70">
            <option value="0" selected="">0</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
          </select>
          <br>
          <span class="ageCount" id="lbInfant">(Age &lt;2)</span>
        </div>
        <div class="depCol1">
          <label for="class" id="lbClass">Class</label>
          <br>
          <select name="selcabinclass" id="class" class="wth150">
            <option selected="" value="0">Economy Class</option>
            <option value="1">Business Class</option>
            <option value="2">First Class</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="depCol1">
          <label for="payBy" id="lbpayBy">Pay By</label>
          <br>
          <select name="payBy" id="payBy" class="wth130">
            <option value="KNET">K-Net</option>
            <option selected="" value="CC">Credit Card</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="depCol2">
          <label for="promocode" id="lbPromoCode">Promo Code</label>
          <br>
          <input type="text" name="promocode" id="promocode" class="wth100 margin10">
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <br />
        <br />
        <div>
          <input name="btnFindFlight" type="button" class="searchBtn" id="btnFindFlight" value="Find Flights">
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <hr />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```